# sub domain pointed to the wrong website folder

Tags: django, nginx

I have a linux server that run multiple different website on multiple different domain which are working fine.

But I created a sub domain for one of the domain which is `demo.mywebsitedomain.com` I did the configuration like it was a different domain which mean I created a specific nginx socket  / service / nginx config file for this subdomain

But when I go the my link `demo.mywebsitedomain.com` it run the website application of an other django application folder, it not the one who I have pointed in the socket and service file. I am verry confuse.

It should run the django application whos in the `testdemo` folder but instead it run a different folder application. Those are the file I created for the subdomain

sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/testdemo.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/testdemo.sock

Environment="PATH=/usr/bin:/home/tiber/testdemo/env/bin"

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/testdemo.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=testdemo.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tiber
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/tiber/testdemo
ExecStart=/home/tiber/testdemo/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/testdemo.sock \
          mysite.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/testdemo

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name demo.mywebsitedomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/testdemo;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/testdemo;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/testdemo.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what folder is your settings.py located?

Comment: testdemo/mysite/settings.py

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code.  I do not have an `Environment` in my **.socket** but I don't think that's the problem.  I take it you already linked your sites-available to to sites-enabled `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`?

Comment: why ```mysite``` I think it should be ```sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/testdemo /etc/nginx/sites-enabled```

Comment: You're right.  I just meant if you ran the command.  Sorry.

Comment: Ok yes, I already ran this command. I double checked to make sure.